# How to get rid of extra white pixels on Alpha Blend mode?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

How can i get rid of these extra pixels when adding a texture (with alpha) on Alpha Blend mode? Alpha blend result seems almost the same as my original PNG, but it does add an extra line of white pixels, even if that isnt on the image. If i use Alpha clip i can get a sharper image, but thats exactly what i dont need this time, i need the image to be true as possible to the original (with alpha)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps a higher bit image would work. TIFF, 16bitPNG...

Comment: Thanks, does this problem happen because of the resolution or format?

Comment: Hi :). I'd say the bit depth matters most. But I'm no expert at Eevee, perhaps there are some other ways to make the transition smooth.